# CORS Regex in Node Express Server

Tags: node.js, regex, express, cors

I am creating an `express` server. This is the snippet.

```
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser()); // mainly used to retrieve and store CSSO tokens
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://the.real.url.com:8081");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition, Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
});
```

It is working currently. But I need to replace `https://the.real.url.com:8081` with `regex`. 
First, it can be `https` or just `http`. 
Second, there may or may not be a port. and so forth.

So when I edited it `https?://the.real.url.com:8081` to allow both `http` and `https`.

I get this error 
`The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'https?://the.real.url.com:8081'. Origin 'https://the.real.url.com:8081' is therefore not allowed access.`

I also tried `http(s?)://the.real.url.com:8081`, `https?://*`, and other variations. None of them works.

So I am wondering `Regex` is not allowed? But the wildcard `*` works.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you looked at the cors package for express: https://github.com/expressjs/cors, this allows you to use a regex for the origin:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: /example\.com$/,
  methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

You can also use this package on individual endpoints,e.g.

```
app.get('/test/', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
    res.json({msg: 'Success'});
});
```

Comment: I did. in one of the articles that I read (or another StackOverflow answer), it says if I do the way I did in the snippet, I don't need to use that. That's why I didn't use that. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: Well I hope it gets you a bit further!

Comment: Will this work with `subdomain.example.com`

Comment: Not 100% sure,  I expect subdomain.example.com should work, but you'd need to test it. It will be easy to change the regex if necessary.

Comment: @TerryLennox This *will* match `example.com`, `subdomain.example.com` but also `bad-actor-example.com` allowing an attacker to circumvent cors. If you don't care about the `https://example.com` domain it is enough to include the leading dot in the regex: `origin: /\.example\.com$/`

Answer (score 5):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header can be either:

- `*` to allow from everywhere
- A specific URL with `/` as the path

You cannot put a regular expression there.

---

You *can* apply your regular expression to the `Origin` header in the **request** and, if it matches, copy the value from the `Origin` request header to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

```
var origin = req.get("Origin");
if (origin && origin.match(your_regex)) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
}
```

---

Or you can just use the CORS middleware which [has a configuration option for this situation](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuring-cors-w-dynamic-origin).

Comment: I believe it should be `req.get("origin")` instead, at least for express/connect servers.